# DataTable com jsf

Tags: java, html, xhtml

Estou com uma certa dificuldade em usar o datatable do primefaces junto com o jsf, eu tentei implementa-lo de certa forma:

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:tab title="Alterar Usuarios">
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <p:dataTable var="p" value="#{usuarioController.findAll()}"

                    border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"

                    paginator="true" rows="2" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
                    {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"

                    >

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.id}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.nome}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Sobrenome</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.sobrenome}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Email</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.email}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Data de Nascimento</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.datanascimento}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">CPF</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.cpf}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Senha</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.senha}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Usuario</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="${p.usuario}"></h:outputText>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Opçoes</f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink value="Alterar"
                            action="#{usuarioController.edit(pr)}"></h:commandLink>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="Voltar" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
                    </h:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

mas so me retorna este visual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar, sou novo com primefaces, desde ja grato!

Comment: Seu método `findAll()` está funcionando corretamente, ou seja, ele está fazendo a consulta?

Comment: Sim Techies, se eu não usar o `<p:dataTable></p:dataTable> ` meus campos todos sao exebidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui estar arrumando o seguinte código mudando os `<h:column> </h:column>` por `<p:column> </p:column>`. Caso outra pessoa tenha a mesmo duvida que eu, ae esta a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso. No começo do seu arquivo xhtml coloque:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="dummy" />
    <f:event listener="#{usuarioController.findAll()}"
        type="preRenderView"></f:event>
</f:metadata>
```

Depois no `value` do seu `dataTable` você passa seu `array`

```
value="#{usuarioController.lista}"
```

Comment: techies não deu Certo, mas muito obrigado Pela atenção.

Comment: Está aparecendo algum erro?